# How to get jndi.properties file

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

I want to use my jndi.properties file but it gives me error msg. I am trying to get the file with this code:

```
public class EJBTester {

...

    Properties props;
    InitialContext ctx;
    {
        props = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("/jndi.properties");
        try {
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
}
```

my jndi.properties file is in the main package in my project and looks like that:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost
```

I am using jboss 6.2 eap. The error is following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.<init>(EJBTester.java:26)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:40)
```

in other words this line ctx = new InitialContext(props); cannot load the props.

How to load this jndi.properties file ?

Comment: It's more a resource loading issue than a JNDI issue. Where is the jndi.properties file? Where is the EJBTester class?

Comment: EJBTester is in package com.tutorialspoint.test;. jndi.properties is in the default package but I think jndi file is found because if I change the name it gives me another error which is jndi.properties not found !

Comment: Why? It gets loaded automatically. You don't have to load it yourself.

Comment: OK how to get InitialContext  then ?

Comment: Err, new InitialContext()?

Comment: if the name is `jndi.properties` then the default constructor, `new InitialContext()` loads it by default..